# Loading Large 3D NumPy Array Into Paraview

Tags: vtk, large-data, paraview

What is the best file format to save a large 3D NumPy array to, so I can easily load it into Paraview?

I have a very large 3D NumPy array filled with data points. I am trying to load this large array into Paraview using a few different methods, but I have been unsuccessful. The array has dimensions of (2000, 1500, 200).

So far, I have used `gridToVTK` to convert the array into a `.vtr` file, but `gridToVTK` crashes if the array is much larger than 100MB. I split up the array into smaller more maintainable chunks and saved the chunks as multiple `.vtr` files and stiched them together in Paraview, but this method is too slow and tedious.

I have also tried saving the NumPy array as a `.raw` file and loading that into Paraview, but I have been unsuccessful using that method.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I should try and save this array so that I can easily load it into Paraview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vtk` module to [use a vtkImageImport](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Utilities/VTKWithNumpy/) and then write the resulting imageData with [vtkXMLImageDataWriter](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/ImageData/WriteReadVtkImageData/)

Comment: This looks promising. I am having a hard time figuring out how to get an vtkImageData object from a vtkImageImport object. I have looked through the VTK documentation with no luck, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: vtkImageImport has a `GetOutput()` method